# Simple Form and returned params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Not sure what is going on but I am positive it's because I am a newbie and this is an easy answer.

So, I am using Simple Form to create a new Message that has a belongs to relationship to my Campaign model.  The problem is that while I can see I am getting a campaign_id back in the params, I can't seem to use it.  I am doing a series of inspects and every time I get nil.

Here is my code...

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create

    @id = params[:campaign_id]

    @campaign = Campaign.find_by id: params[:campaign_id]    
  end

  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:campaign_id, :text)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :campaign, collection: Campaign.all, label_method: :client %>
  <%= f.input :text %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

create.html.erb (so I can see what's happening)

```
<%= params.inspect %><br /> <br />
<%= @id.inspect %><br /> <br />
<%= @campaign.inspect %><br /> <br />
```

And here is what I get from the inspects:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"Qh75FhPN+JhDR59IlF376Ythgbk7jkgFrER0vunr/bU=",
>   "message"=>{"campaign_id"=>"1", "text"=>"Here is a test"},
>   "commit"=>"Create Message", "action"=>"create",
>   "controller"=>"messages"}
>
> nil
>
> nil

Let me know if any additional info is required, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`campaign_id` is nested inside `message`. You should access it like

```
params[:message][:campaign_id]
```

Comment: Gah, I knew I was being a total newb!  Thank you!  I'll select as best answer once the timer is up.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `params` incorrectly `params` is a `HashwithIndifferentAccess` so to access your `campaign_id` you must first enter the `hash` for the `message`.

```
params[:message][:campaign_id]
```

Or

```
params['message']['campaign_id']
```

will both work.

```
params[:message]
#=>{"campaign_id"=>"1", "text"=>"Here is a test"}
```